# Data Structures: Infix to Prefix LinkedList(LL)

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, prefix, infix-notation

My code is able to compile and run, however the process returns -1. I have drawn out various test cases manually and believes it works, so I am not sure which part of my logic is wrong.

I ask the user for a infix exp., and `in2PreLL` will

1. reverse the infix exp.
2. insert it into the front of Linked List `inExpLL` or Stack `s` based on the switch-case statements
3. Finally, I reverse the entire `inExpLL` to get the prefix exp.

This code assumes:

1. input string consists only positive integer numbers
2. Only operators are + - * / ( )

I entered the input of `(1+2)+(3-4)`, expecting a prefix exp. of `++12-34` when I draw out the process manually. However, when I run the code, it gives me `Process returned -1 (0xFFFFFFFF)`

**EDIT:**
I have debugged my code and it works now! Thanks for the suggestions everyone!

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates your observations, if necessary with sample input (but better not needing input, e.g. using hardcoded init values), the output you get (including error messages quoted in full, verbatim, as text and directly here) in contrast to the output you expect.

Comment: I have tried including the driver code as well as the sample input to demonstrate my logic. Hope my question is clearer @Yunnosch

Comment: Please read the concept description of [mre] and try to apply it. Usually a MRE only has one code part to copy for reproducing.

Comment: It does not compile: definition of `insertNode()` is missing.

Comment: @Meisner Hi! You're right, I missed the definition out, I have included it in, it can compile now but it still doesn't return the right output

Comment: @newtocodingyikes: there are a number of points that would deserve improvements in this code. As soon as is works, you should post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) in order to get useful advices.

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score 1):

Warnings are not to be ignored:

```
    ...
    default:   //operand
        insertNode(inExpLL, atoi(c), OPERAND);
    ...
```

My compiler croaks with

```
incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'
```

And indeed `atoi(c)` is plain wrong here. To convert a single digit to its numeric value, you should use `c - '0'`.

Even worse, your code uses the deprecated `gets` and uses it badly: it should at least be:

```
    gets(infix, stdin);
```

Finally: you really should learn how to use a debugger...

---

With the added code and my 2 fixes, the code gives :

```
 4  3  +  2  1  +  )  +  )
```

so still the closing paren to remove and the opposite order...

Comment: thank you for your help, I have included the definition of insertNode which I missed out before. can i ask why is atoi wrong here though? I thought atoi is used to convert a string/char into an integer data type?

Comment: @newtocodingyikes: `atoi` parameter is expected to be a C string, that is a pointer to a null terminated char array. Not a single character.